# Regarding Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I have extracted the following from Ahlfors's Complex Analysis:

> > To prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\right|^2\le\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|a_i\right|^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|b_i\right|^2$$Let $\lambda$ denote an arbitrary complex number and we can obtain
> >     \begin{equation}
> > \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|a_i-\lambda\bar{b_i}\right|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|a_i\right|^2+\left|\lambda\right|^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|b_i\right|^2-2\operatorname{Re}\left(\bar{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\right)\qquad\qquad(1)
> > \end{equation}
> >     Since this expression is $\ge0$ for all $\lambda$, we can choose $$\lambda=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|b_i\right|^2}$$so as to make $(1)$ as small as possible.

My problem is how $\lambda$ is being chosen.

Comment: To make the right hand side as small as possible, for a fixed $|\lambda|$, we need to pick $\lambda$ in the same direction as $\sum a_i b_i$, so that $\overline{\lambda}\sum a_i b_i$ is a nonnegative real number. So write $\lambda = \lambda_0 \sum a_i b_i$ with $\lambda_0$ real. After some manipulation, the expression to be minimized will be a quadratic function of $\lambda_0$, so you just need to take the $\lambda_0$-coordinate of the vertex of its graph.

Comment: You question is not clear.  Ahlfors is choosing $\lambda$ to be equal to the given fraction. Is your question, about how he is allowed to do that? Or, why $\lambda$ minimizes (1)? Or is it some other issue?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski The question is why it was a good idea to choose that $\lambda$, or perhaps why it was predictable that it would be a good idea.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski My question is why $\lambda$ minimizes $(1)$.

Comment: @user208259 Why do we pick $\lambda$ such that $\overline{\lambda}\sum a_i b_i$ is a nonnegative real number, can't it be complex?

Comment: Yes, it can but that will not minimize the expression. See my answer below.

Comment: @Sapphire You want to maximize the real part of $\overline{\lambda} \sum a_i b_i$. If the modulus of $\lambda$ is held fixed, and you change only its argument, this corresponds to performing a rotation. The result with maximum real part occurs when $\overline{\lambda} \sum a_i b_i$ is real and nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To minimize the right hand side of (1), first consider all $\lambda$ with a fixed modulus.
The expression will be minimized among those choices of $\lambda$ which make the last term as large as possible. Let $\lambda=z_1$ and $\sum a_ib_i=z_2$ to simplify the notation.

Multipling $z_2$ by $\overline{z_1}$ will rescale $z_2$ to have modulus $|z_1||z_2|$ and
rotate $z_2$ by $-\text{arg }z_1$.  In other words, letting $z_1$ vary by its argument only will make $\overline{z_1}z_2$ trace out a circular path whose center is at $0$ and whose radius is $|z_1z_2|$.  So which of these values has the largest real part?  Clearly, the one
on the positive real axis. In other words, $\text{arg}(\overline{z_1}z_2)=-\text{arg }z_1+\text{arg }z_2=0$. So $\text{arg }z_1=\text{arg }z_2$. In other, words $\lambda$ must be in the same direction as $\sum a_ib_i$.